# Swagger : Multiple locations for API not being picked up

Tags: java, maven, swagger

In my project there are different packages containing Rest APIs

```
e.g.
com.mypackage.rest
com.mypackage2.rest
com.mypackage3.rest
```

I want to document all those.

I have a maven project having swagger plugin where in locations I am trying to specify multiple locations for Rest API as following

```
<locations>
  com.mypackage.rest;
  com.mypackage2.rest;
  com.mypackage3.rest
</locations>
```

But when I do mvn clean install, it is not generating swagger json file.

PS. If I am using only one location, json file is being generated properly. Also if I try to put it as following, only last package json file is getting generated.

```
<locations>com</locations>
```

Need help!

Comment: Did you find a solution for that problem?

Comment: It always overwrites, I ended up having different definitions for different modules. different paths for different module swagger too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Did you try something like this: com.mypackage*? I could solve it for my case since all classes were in the same package: com.example.rest.* worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

`<locations>com.mypackage.rest;com.mypackage2.rest;com.mypackage3.rest</locations>` should do the trick, at least it works for me (version 3.1.x)

In the future (not yet released) the syntax will be:

> <locations>
>     <location>com.mypackage.rest</location>
>     <location>com.mypackage2.rest</location>
>     <location>com.mypackage3.rest</location>
>   </locations>

See https://github.com/kongchen/swagger-maven-plugin/issues/328

Comment: I was using <locations>value</locations> with version 3.1.3... when i increased the version to 3.1.7, i faced an issue related to locations. I had to add <location> inside the locations element to make it work. Same happened for the scheme. Reference: https://github.com/kongchen/swagger-maven-plugin